# Which allotropes of sulfur exist naturally?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, elements, allotropes

I'm writing a paper on chemistry and I would like to know which allotropes of sulfur exist naturally. I've searched on the Internet but I haven't found anything about natural sulfur allotropes except this book(Ref. 1). Does anyone know the answer?

**Reference**

1. Steudel R., Eckert B. () Solid Sulfur Allotropes. In: Steudel R. (eds) Elemental Sulfur and Sulfur-Rich Compounds I. Topics in Current Chemistry, vol 230. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, DOI: [doi.org/10.1007/b12110](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2Fb12110)

Comment: Even the elemental sulfur in its most common yellow powder form is rare. I would be surprised if any other would exist. Maybe temporarily, in active vulcans, a very little bit of.

Comment: _Some_ browsing in Wikipedia, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_sulfur) suggests only $\alpha$ and $\gamma$-form are found naturally in significant amounts at ambient conditions.  The $\beta{}$ form probably only if the molten sulfur drops into nearby water, but over time, it is not a stable form.  But varying pressure and temperature changes the typical $\ce{S8}$ molecule.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thanks for the answer! However, from the reference that I provided above, I already know that $\alpha{}$ and $\gamma{}$-$\ce{S8}$ naturally occur.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Oh, okay, I'll add a self-answer. Thanks!

Comment: I just answered: [How do native sulfur crystals form?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71134/how-do-native-sulfur-crystals-form/151260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha and [gamma form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosick%C3%BDite) of cyclo-S<sub>8</sub> are the only forms to occur naturally. Besides the reference provided in the question, you can also find more information in the [wikipedia article of "sulfur allotropes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_sulfur).